# Cannot launch application to smart TV via Tizen studio

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to launch a sample application to my smart tv UE49KU6400 through Tizen studio.
My TV is configured in developer mode with my PC IP.
I have added also the TV in my connection manager in Tizen studio.
I have generated also a certificate profile via the studio.
I am using Tizen Studio 2.0 and have created a TV v4.0 project and firmware on TV is 1201 version ( the latest for this model according to latest updates).
When I am trying to lauch application on smart TV I get an error 'Closed'.
Console logs show :

```
11:06:30 E/sdb: sdb rejected shell command (pkgcmd -l | grep owStEM7jOZ --word-regexp): closed
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Basically the error just mentions sdb tried retrieving your app and the command was rejected, though it doesn't tell us why. Hard to debug based on that info, but you should check out the usual suspects: Is there enough storage space? Do you have priveleges, which cause trouble? Remove all priveleges you don't absolutely need and retry.

Comment: I am getting this same error and I cannot figure it out either.

Comment: Might be a certificate type issue. When you create the certificate, you can choose either Tizen or Samsung. Previously I used samsung and it was fine, but then deploys stopped working with the studio and tv extension update. After switching to a Tizen certificate, the deploys work again.

Comment: the project which you are trying to launch is a new project created by you in the tizen studio or you are importing some project ?

Answer (score 1):

If you created your certificate with Public Level and if you use Partner Level priviliges, TV will not install and tell nothing. First of all if you do not need Partner Level priviliges remove all and retry. Or check what i have experienced https://stackoverflow.com/a/52984855/1766100