# Installing App to Samsung Tizen TV with Partner Level Certificate

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I had a problem to install developed app to Samsung TV device. Now I got a solution and i want to share my experience. Problem occurs if you add Partner Level Priviliges like http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/drminfo http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/drmplay and http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/productinfo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You need Tizen IDE to do all of these.
   https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download
2. Open Tools > Package Manager and be sure you have installed Main SDK > Certificate Manager, Extension SDK > Samsung Certificate Extension.
3. Open Tools > Device Manager and connect to TV Device.(Connecting the TV and SDK)
   https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-device
4. Right click connected device and select DUID. Copy device DUID.
5. Open Tools > Certificate Manager and follow steps at link (Select Partner while creating)
   https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch/develop/getting-certificates/create

   At the DUID step paste copied DUID.
6. After creating certificate, open Tools > Device Manager select connected device and click right. After that you have to select "Permit to install applications"
   https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch/develop/getting-certificates/permit
7. Now you can add partner level priviliges to your config file.
8. You are ready to install TV.

Comment: Thanks so much especially for the step 6 which I forgot to do! The entire process is rather complicated if you ask me.

Comment: Tizen app installation is really headache :)

Comment: @FatihÇelik Great, it works with Samsung Partner certificate. By any chance, do you happen to know if there is any possibility to make it work also with Tizen Partner certificate?

Comment: https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/setting-up-sdk/creating-certificates.html

Answer (score 3):

Addition to Faith Celik answer, a fix to my problem, make sure your TV is connect to public network.

My laptop and TV are behind a proxy network. Even though they are connected, when i follow Faith's 8th step. The Tizen Studio return error:

```
Installing the package... > Fail
Unexpected error occurred at the below step.
 `Installing the package...`
Tizen Web Application install failed. Please try again later.
```

without any further error.

The deal was, TV need to validate the Samsung Certificate to install, and it can not do that without a public internet connection.

After i connect my laptop and TV through a public wifi and follow Faith's 8 steps, the app installation went smoothly without an error.

My configure version:

- Tizen Studio: 3.3.
- TV Extension: 3.0, 4.0, 5.0.
- TV Emulator: 5.0.
- Real TV platform: 4.0.

Comment: In my case I just restart the TV holding the power button 4 seconds. It was a TV bug, I figure out because I tried to delete an existing app on the tv and it didn't, but I had the same error you show here